# locating somebody on IRC servers over the Internet

Tags: irc, privacy, ircd

Is there a way to locate somebody by his nick or IP address on the internet's IRC servers?

I guess the protocol doesn't seem to support it! Still... can it be done? like crawling the web for IRC servers and injecting bots to query about if that nick/IP is online on one of the channels?

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### search engines

The simplest way I've ever seen is to use a service such as searchirc.com.

- http://searchirc.com/whois

[image: ss of searchirc]

#### web frontends

Some of the IRC servers provide web frontends to the `/whois` command so if you know someone frequents a particular IRC server you can search for them using those. For example:

- [DALnet IRC Network](https://users.dal.net/user_search.php)

#### lists

Lastly there are lists of servers so you can go through the various servers and look for users in a brute force kind of fashion.

- [IRC Networks and Server Lists](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/networks/)

Comment: No server list is exhaustive, though. Just like Google cannot find pages they don't know about.